# Why the code does not loop when user enter incorrect lowercase letter

Tags: c++

I am writing a code that generates a random number then assign the number to a letter in string letters then user has to guess the letter.

I am trying to loop the the question "Enter one lowercase letter: " if the user enters a letter that does not match `randomLetter`, but at the same time I have to make sure the letter is all in lower case (something we haven't learned in class but after searching I found a solution, hopefully it's the right way to go about it).

This `while` loop ends if user enters the incorrect lower letter. It does work when the `letterGuess` matches `randomLetter`.

The other thing I have to do is if user enters an incorrect lower letter then it needs to give feedback that the correct letter comes before or after the entered letter.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//function prototype
void displayNumber(int);

int main()
{
    string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string randomLetter;
    string letterGuess = "";
    string wordLocation = " ";
    int randomNumber = 0;

    //display random number then assign a random number to letter string
    displayNumber(randomNumber);
    randomLetter = letters[randomNumber];

    while (letterGuess.length() != 1) {
        //ask user to enter a lowercase letter and determine if it matches the random letter
        cout << "Enter one lowercase letter: ";
        getline(cin, letterGuess);

        if (all_of(letterGuess.begin(), letterGuess.end(), &::isupper)) {
            cout << "letter must be lowercase.";
        }
        else if (randomLetter.find(letterGuess, 0) == -1) {
            cout << "\nYou guessed the correct letter.";
        }
        else {
            wordLocation.insert(0, letters);
        } //end if
    } //end while
    return 0;
} //end of main function

void displayNumber(int num)
{
    srand(time(0));
    num = (rand() % 26) + 1;
    cout << num << endl
         << endl;
} // end of displayNumber function
```

Comment: The Code does not seem to be clear. The description says that you enter *one* letter, but the code takes a string and loop exits if the input is single letter

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it yet, [you shouldn't be `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6296561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problems you highlighted is caused by the looping condition,

```
while(letterGuess.length() != 1)
```

here when the user in the first iteration enters just one letter, the `letterGuess` string will have size = 1, and hence will cause breaking of loop.

Another problem is the fact that `randomNumber` remains 0, for it not to remain zero the `displayNumber` function must take a reference or return a value.

**EDIT**

To update `randomNumber`, modify the display function to :

```
int displayNumber()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int num = (rand() % 26) + 1;
    cout << num << endl
         << endl;
    return num;
}
```

and in the main:

```
randomNumber = displayNumber();
```

or alternatively

```
void displayNumber(int& num)
{
    srand(time(0));
    num = (rand() % 26) + 1;
    cout << num << endl
         << endl;
}
```

and in the main:

```
displayNumber(randomNumber);
```

maybe rename it to `generateRandom()` which seems more accurate?

Comment: WOW good catch about displayNumber() function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i see what you are saying, i am trying to figure out how to return # to randomNumber now lol

Comment: @SanaJ do consider accepting the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 2):

You  your problem might be is here:

```
while (letterGuess.length() != 1)
```

because you when you enter one character you break the loop. To fix this you might go different routes, but easiest one is to check if letter is lower or upper.

```
while (letterGuess.length() != 1 || std::islower(letterGuess[0]))
```

Also now that I look at it closer, did you want to check if any characters in string are upper or all of them are upper?

```
all_of(letterGuess.begin(), letterGuess.end(), &::isupper)
```

would check if all characters are lower, but to check if only one character is upper use `any_of()`

```
any_of(letterGuess.begin(), letterGuess.end(), &::isupper)
```

Here is my little example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main (void) {
    std::string s = "Hello";
    if (any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), &::isupper))
        std::cout << "One is upper\n\n";

    if (all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), &::isupper))
        std::cout << "All are upper\n";
    else
        std::cout << "some might be upper\n";                                                                                               

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
EXECUTING       ==================================================

One is upper

some might be upper

DONE            ==================================================
```

Since you are newbie, another thing that I just noticed that I still remember from my newbie days. call `srand(time(0));` once. Maybe at the begging of `main()`. Way you have it does produces the same `random` number every time. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: should check for all because string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; all are lowercase.

Comment: i am fairly new to this language this is my first class, takes a while to learn stuff :D

Comment: @SanaJ been there do not worry!!! To answer your first comment, you are than modifying `letterGuess`  in  `getline(cin, letterGuess);` and checking if any letters in input are capitalized.

Comment: Yeah, i think i was trying to figure out best way to check the `letterGuess` must be lowercase or it produces an error saying letter must be lowercase. but like you said it's modifying it then this is not the best way. What other ways can i check if letter entered is lowercase? Also thank you for taking your time to reply to me and the info on `srand(time(0));` i am reading it now.

Comment: @SanaJ I see your problem now!!! when you enter incorect one character `!=1` is true. see my edit

Comment: Aha! so i need to loop it till the answer is correct and not stop at 1 letter entered, I see, you're the best. Let me see what i can do with the edits and guidance you provided, thank you sir!

Comment: I used do while loop `while(letterGuess != randomLetter || isupper(letterGuess[0]));` which resolved the issue, thank you again! my entire code is working as intended!